# Printing a member from the object returned by itr.next()

Tags: java, iterator

The following code has compilation issues. The compilation error is also attached. Please suggest solution to the same.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

class test{

    int key;

    public static void main(String []args){
        test obj = new test();
        obj.key = 9999;

        LinkedList al = new LinkedList();
        al.add(obj);

        Iterator itr = al.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            test temp = new test();
            temp = itr.next();
            System.out.println(temp.key);
        }   
    }
}
```

**Compilation Error :**

> test.java:17: error: incompatible types
>
> temp = itr.next();
>                                          ^
>
> required: test
>
> found:    Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`its.next()` returns an instance of `Object` and not the `Test`

Make it as follows

```
LinkedList<Test> al = new LinkedList<Test>();
al.add(obj);

Iterator<Test> itr = al.iterator();
```

So compiler now knows that `LinkedList` `a1` can only hold `Test` instances so while iterating we will only have instances of `Test`

Comment: You are welcome (also to mark the answer which helped you as answered by clicking right mark near to answer)

Comment: For anyone that wants more information on Generics, [this site](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) has tons.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

#### Old Solution ( Pre Java 1.5 ):

```
public static void main(String []args){
    test obj = new test();
    obj.key = 9999;

    LinkedList al = new LinkedList();
    al.add(obj);

    Iterator itr = al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        test temp = new test();
        // use type cast
        temp = (test) itr.next();
        System.out.println(temp.key);
    }   
}
```

#### Generic Solution (Java 1.5 and later):

```
public static void main(String []args){
    test obj = new test();
    obj.key = 9999;

    LinkedList<test> al = new LinkedList<test>();
    al.add(obj);

    Iterator<test> itr = al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        test temp = new test();
        // use Generic
        temp = itr.next();
        System.out.println(temp.key);
    }   
}
```